# Altium Sheet information not updating

Tags: altium

I had a question regarding Altium Designer, it should be very simple but I have now tried everything I could find but could not get the sheet information in the bottom-right corner to update.

As I read on the internet it should update automatically when changing the parameters in the properties panel, but as you can see it does not change when putting information here. I know it should be simple but I would really appreciate it if someone could help me figure this out, should I do something such that the information on the sheet refreshes?

[image]

Comment: I am using Altium 22.5.1

Comment: You should ***edit*** your question with that information rather than add it as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

You are modifying sheet parameters, but for them to appear on your sheet they need to be implemented on the sheet template you are using.

Try selecting different template: go to Design->Sheet Templates->Local (select one of the available templates or Load from file).

Default location of Altium templates: C:\Users\Public\Documents\Altium\AD21\Templates

They are files with SchDot extension.
You can create your own template based on those examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to compile the project.

Comment: Can you expand this answer?

Comment: If there are labels, they will be updated on redraw (e.g. moving/zooming the sheet) at the latest, reading from SCH or PRJ parameters; I'm not aware of a situation where compile has an effect on labels.